# created a function but getting error as “correlated subqueriy is a query that references a column from outaide that subquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Create Or replace function
mdb.fun_brand_cd_values(store_number string, invoice_date date) as
(( select case when invoice_date is null
then
(select case when store_type= ‘GASC’ THEN ‘Gas’
else store_type
end
from mdb.retail_store_liat
where store_num = store_number